# HTTP 400 - status when adding argument to my Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, blob

I am using Spring MVC and have a form that looks like this : https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/1526193_10152219199443013_1553859401_n.jpg

On the form there is a button for uploading pictures and when I try to get the file into my controller using an argument I get HTTP-400 status when i press the ok button.

What is the problem and how to fix this issue with files

My jsp code :

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="editPersonBean" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <form:hidden path="id" />

        <table class="myTable">
            <c:if test="${editPersonBean.id > 0}">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <td>${editPersonBean.id}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:if>
            <tr>
                <td>Förnamn</td>
                <td><form:input path="firstName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Efternamn</td>
                <td><form:input path="lastName" /></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Telefon nummer</td>
                <td><form:input path="phoneNumber" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>E-Mail</td>
                <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Övrigt</td>
                <td><form:input path="otherInfo" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Bild</td>
                <td><form:label path ="image" />
                <input type="file" name="file" /> 
            </td>
            </tr>
            <br>
            <br>
            <tr>
                <td><c:set var="submitText">
                    OK
                </c:set> <input type="submit" size="20" value="${submitText}" /> <a
                    href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/person.html"></a></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

When I am passing in this argument into the controller to catch up the uploaded file its then I get the problem.

```
@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
```

And the controller I am having problem with looks like the following :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/editPerson/{id}.html")
public class EditPersonContoller {

    @Autowired
    PersonService service;


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index(@PathVariable int id) {

        EditPersonBean bean = new EditPersonBean();

        if (id > 0) {
            Person person = service.getPerson(id);
            bean.copyValuesToBean(person);
        }

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("editPerson");
        mav.addObject("editPersonBean", bean);
        return mav;

    }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView handleSubmit(EditPersonBean bean, BindingResult errors, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

            if (errors.hasErrors()) {
                ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("editPerson");
                mav.addObject("editPersonBean", bean);
                return mav;
            }

            if (bean.getId() > 0) {
                Person person = service.getPerson((int) bean.getId());
                bean.copyBeanValuesToPerson(person);
                saveImage(person, file);
                service.updatePerson(person);

            } else {
                Person person = new Person();
                bean.copyBeanValuesToPerson(person);
                saveImage(person, file);
                service.createPerson(person);
            }

            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/person.html");
        }


        public void saveImage(Person person, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {



           try {

               Blob blob = Hibernate.createBlob(file.getInputStream());

                      person.setImage(blob);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Also I am trying to save the picture using a bean :

public class EditPersonBean {

```
private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String phoneNumber;
private String otherInfo;
private Blob image;

public void copyValuesToBean(Person person){

    setId((int) person.getId());
    setFirstName(person.getFirstName());
    setLastName(person.getLastName());
    setEmail(person.getEmail());
    setPhoneNumber(person.getPhoneNumber());
    setOtherInfo(person.getOtherInfo());
    setImage(person.getImage());

}

public void copyBeanValuesToPerson(Person person){

    person.setId((int) getId());
    person.setFirstName(getFirstName());
    person.setLastName(getLastName());
    person.setEmail(getEmail());
    person.setPhoneNumber(getPhoneNumber());
    person.setOtherInfo(getOtherInfo());
    person.setImage(image);

}


public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}
public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
public String getOtherInfo() {
    return otherInfo;
}
public void setOtherInfo(String otherInfo) {
    this.otherInfo = otherInfo;
}

public Blob getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(Blob image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

}

And  I am trying to save it into the database through a service that just calls the repository :

```
@Override
    public void createPerson(Person person) {
        session.getCurrentSession().save(person);
    }
```

And finally it should go down to the model and persist it into the database:

```
@Column(name = "image")
@Lob
private Blob image;
```

But no image is being saved into the database and instead the page return an http : 400- Status.

Whats the problem here?

Comment: Do you have a `MultipartResolver` bean in your context?

Comment: No, how to configure that?

Comment: @Sembrano can u share your full code on GITHUB or any repository so its easy to debug

Comment: Sure : https://bitbucket.org/Josef_Lowdin/civilforsvaret_webapp

Answer (score 0):

The [Spring MVC documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart) explains its support for multipart file uploading.

Basically, you need to provide a `MultipartResolver` in the `ApplicationContext` that will be available to the `DispatcherServlet`. You have a few options. A common one is `CommonsMultipartResolver`, for which you will need Apache's `commons-fileupload.jar`. The documentation provides the following example

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>
```

The `DispatcherServlet` will detect this bean in your `ApplicationContext` and register it so that it can process requests that have a `Content-Type` of `multipart/...`. On each such request, it will wrap the `HttpServletRequest` in a `MultipartHttpServletRequest`.

Spring uses a `RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver` to resolve arguments for parameters annotated with `@RequestParam` in your `@RequestMapping` annotated handler methods.

If the parameter is also of type `MultipartFile`, Spring will cast the `HttpServletRequest` to a `MultipartHttpServletRequest` created earlier and use it to retrieve the parts, one of which is your `file`.

If this configuration is not done, the whole process fails and you likely get a 400 Bad Request.

Comment: @Sembrano Let's see your updated context configuration (might as well add your web.xml too).

Comment: @Sembrano Aslo, your form doesn't seem to be submitted to the right place or with the right request method. I don't see a `POST`.

Comment: @Sembrano You have a handler, but nothing is actually sending a POST (not from what you've shown us).

Comment: @Sembrano Open up your browser's Network Console (if you don't know what that is, google it) and perform your submit. Check the request headers and body to see if you are submitting what you think you are. Then check if you have the appropriate handler method.

Answer (score -3):

how you are getting file in the controller which is uploaded by the JSP, put the below method in your controller and debug your code

```
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
        throws Exception {

        FileUpload file = (FileUpload)command;

        MultipartFile multipartFile = file.getFile();

        String fileName="";

        if(multipartFile!=null){
            fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
            //do whatever you want
        }

            System.out.println("filename :" + fileName);     
        return new ModelAndView("FileUploadSuccess","fileName",fileName);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, Sir it cannot cast the file "file.getFile();"

Comment: @Sembrano please create this model in your model package  package com.abc.model;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
 
public class FileUpload{
 
 MultipartFile file;
 //getter and setter methods
 
}

Comment: @Sembrano if this solution works for you please right click on my answer my friend, so it will be useful for others.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis he will able to debug that is he able to get the file which is uploaded or not

Comment: The method as you provided it will not be registered as a handler. It's completely random and will not be invoked.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, if he would be able to work with spring then he can set his handler accordingly everything on the board will become spoon fitting for him as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. Obviously OP doesn't know Spring very well, but this answer does not help.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis my friend he has debug that class u can read the comments and he was facing an issue in type casting so i have said to hime to create one entity class, I thought so i have done great help of him.

Comment: The method you provided is the Spring 2 way of doing things and has nothing to do with OP's Spring 3 way of doing things with `@RequestMapping` annotated methods. It's just a random method in in a class. Spring knows nothing about it.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis spring 3 supports spring 2 as well, so why are you downgrading me

Comment: Yes but you haven't explained how. OP's controller class is standalone. It doesn't extend the spring  2 `SimpleController` class (or whatever it's called). Even if it did, what you are proposing is equivalent to what OP currently has. Also I didn't downvote but I do feel your answer is not very useful at this point.